# Guacamole image in Docker getting blank login page

Tags: docker, centos6, guacamole

I did a docker pull for images guacd, guacamole and mysql latest on CentOS VM box version 6.6. configured them as with glyptodon. But when I open the web page I only get a blank page and no login frame. The guacamole client image stack trace says Unknown Database, I checked the classpath set for guacamole.properties twice where i'm providing the db connections, but found all well there. I'm clueless here.

Something tricky part is missing. Any one kindly suggest where am i going wrong in db configuration that is resulting into blank page without login frame. Thanks.!
Attaching image here -

[image]

Comment: Are there exceptions written in logs files inside containers?

Comment: Yes Gile, the container log indicates that UserMapper.xml is faulty or missing. 

### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'guacamole_db'
### The error may exist in org/apache/guacamole/auth/jdbc/user/UserMapper.xml
### The error may involve org.apache.guacamole.auth.jdbc.user.UserMapper.selectOne
### The error occurred while executing a query
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'guacamole_db'

Comment: Just going through the user-mapping xml configuration and GUACAMOLE_HOME settings. I would be delighted if you make me understand the use of this xml file and how and where to configure it in best way. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

About the `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'guacamole_db'`, it seems the database is not yet initialized.

Double-check the steps about db initialization written in [glyptodon/guacamole-docker README.md](https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-docker)

> Initializing the MySQL
>
> If your database is not already initialized with the Guacamole schema,
>   you will need to do so prior to using Guacamole. A convenience script
>   for generating the necessary SQL to do this is included in the
>   Guacamole image.
>
> To generate a SQL script which can be used to initialize a fresh MySQL
>   database [as documented in the Guacamole manual](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/jdbc-auth.html#jdbc-auth-mysql):
>
> docker run --rm glyptodon/guacamole /opt/guacamole/bin/initdb.sh
>   --mysql > initdb.sql
>
> Alternatively, you can use the SQL scripts included with
>   [guacamole-auth-jdbc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guacamole/files/current/extensions/guacamole-auth-jdbc-0.9.6.tar.gz/download).
>
> Once this script is generated, you must:
>
> ```
> Create a database for Guacamole within MySQL, such as guacamole_db.
> Create a user for Guacamole within MySQL with access to this database, such as guacamole_user.
> Run the script on the newly-created database.
> ```
>
> The process for doing this via the mysql utility included with MySQL
>   is documented in the [Guacamole manual](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/jdbc-auth.html#jdbc-auth-mysql).

Comment: Appreciate your kind reply. Actually I have already done the guacamole_db setup with recommended schema required according to the above manual you provided. But i am unable to make use of guacamole.properties which provides mysql configuration while deploying guacamole, i guess. Can you please suggest how to configure Or set path of - 1. guacamole.properties 2. Location of guacd tomcat which is running on localhost (look at image attached above). I have donloaded guacamole war but failing to provide DB config and deploy it in guacd default tomcat server. Thanks.!

Comment: guacamole.properties - 
guacd-hostname: localhost
guacd-port:     4822
# MySQL properties
auth-provider: net.sourceforge.guacamole.net.auth.mysql.MySQLAuthenticationProvider
mysql-hostname: localhost
mysql-port: 3306
mysql-database: guacamole_db
mysql-username: guacamole
mysql-password: root
# Location to read extra .jar's from
lib-directory:  /var/lib/guacamole/classpath
# Authentication provider class
# Properties used by BasicFileAuthenticationProvider
basic-user-mapping: /etc/guacamole/user-mapping.xml

Comment: I'm unable to find the tomcat8 location which is default server in guacd as per document. Where i need to place guacamole.war to deploy. Do i also need to download and place jars like mysql connector ?

Answer (score 0):

After digging out the documents, i'm able to run Guacamole in Docker container on CentOS 6.6 running in Oracle VM box and eventually able to connect remote systems like charm..

Here are the following steps that i followed -

**1.** yum install --nogpgcheck -y yum-utils

**2.** yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

**3.** yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo

**4.** yum makecache fast

**5.** yum install --nogpgcheck docker-io

**6.** docker pull guacamole/guacd:0.9.11-incubating

**7.** docker pull guacamole/guacamole:0.9.11-incubating

**8.** docker pull mysql:8

**9.** docker run --name guacd -d guacamole/guacd:0.9.11-incubating

**10.** docker run --rm guacamole/guacamole:0.9.11-incubating /opt/guacamole/bin/initdb.sh --mysql > initdb.sql

(I ran the initdb.sql scripts manually through workbench to create guacamole schema in my guacamole db.)

**11.** docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=guacamole -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=guacamole -d -p 3306:3306 mysql:8

**12.** docker run --name guacamole --link guacd:guacd --link mysql:mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=guacamole -e MYSQL_USER=guacamole -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=guacamole -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=guacamole -d -p 8080:8080 guacamole/guacamole:0.9.11-incubating

Hit http://localhost:8080/guacamole

Input guacadmin/guacadmin as username and password in login page. Done.!

Happy Dockerizing..!!

Thanks to @Gile for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, docker mysql image has been updated, and thus the latest tag is now pointing to 8.0+ rather than 5.7. Not sure why, but Mysql 8 doesn't seem to be compatible with guacamole 0.9.14. You can simply downgrade mysql by specifying image tag as 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Tripped over this same symptom with a new installation. MySQL comes configured to listen to the loop-back adapter only. Changed it to listen on "any" network connection, restarted and all is fine.